# Freefem++: Solving poisson equation with numerical function

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-element-analysis, freefem++

I am using Freefem++ to solve the poisson equation

Grad^2 u(x,y,z) = -f(x,y,z)

It works well when I have an analytical expression for f, but now I have an f numerically defined (i.e. a set of data defined on a mesh) and I am wondering if I can still use Freefem++.

I.e. typical code (for a 2D problem in this case), looks like the following

```
mesh Sh= square(10,10); // mesh generation of a square
fespace Vh(Sh,P1); // space of P1 Finite Elements
Vh u,v; // u and v belongs to Vh

func f=cos(x)*y; // analytical function

problem Poisson(u,v)= // Definition of the problem
    int2d(Sh)(dx(u)*dx(v)+dy(u)*dy(v)) // bilinear form
    -int2d(Sh)(f*v) // linear form
    +on(1,2,3,4,u=0); // Dirichlet Conditions
Poisson; // Solve Poisson Equation
plot(u); // Plot the result
```

I am wondering if I can define f numerically, rather than analytically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Mesh & space Definition**

We define a square unit with Nx=10 mesh and Ny=10 this provides 11 nodes on x axis and the same for y axis.

```
int Nx=10,Ny=10;
int Lx=1,Ly=1;
mesh Sh= square(Nx,Ny,[Lx*x,Ly*y]); //this is the same as square(10,10)
fespace Vh(Sh,P1); // a space of P1 Finite Elements to use for u definition
```

**Conditions and problem statement**

We are not going to use solve but we ll handle matrix (a more sophisticated way to solve with FreeFem).

First we define CL for our problem (Dirichlet ones).

```
varf CL(u,psi)=on(1,2,3,4,u=0); //you can eliminate border according to your problem state
    Vh u=0;u[]=CL(0,Vh);
    matrix GD=CL(Vh,Vh);
```

Then we define the problem.  Instead of writing `dx(u)*dx(v)+dy(u)*dy(v)` I suggest to use macro, so we define div as following but pay attention macro finishes by `//` NOT `;`.

```
 macro div(u) (dx(u[0])+dy(u[1])) //
```

So Poisson bilinear form becomes:

```
varf Poisson(u,v)= int2d(Sh)(div(u)*div(v));
```

After we extract Stifness Matrix

```
matrix K=Poisson(Vh,Vh);
matrix KD=K+GD; //we add CL defined above
```

We proceed for solving, UMFPACK is a solver in FreeFem no much attention to this.

```
set(KD,solver=UMFPACK);
```

And here what you need.  You want to define a value of function f on some specific nodes.  I'm going to give you the secret, the poisson linear form.

```
real[int] b=Poisson(0,Vh);
```

You define value of the function f at any node you want to do.

```
b[100]+=20; //for example at node 100 we want that f equals to 20
b[50]+=50; //and at node 50 , f equals to 50
```

We solve our system.

```
u[]=KD^-1*b;
```

Finally we get the plot.

```
plot(u,wait=1);
```

I hope this will help you, thanks to my internship supervisor Olivier, he always gives to me tricks specially on FreeFem.  I tested it, it works very well.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The method by **afaf** works in the case when the function `f` is a free-standing one. For the terms like `int2d(Sh)(f*u*v)`, another solution is required. I propose (actually I have red it somewhere in Hecht's manual) an approach that covers both cases. However, it works only for `P1` finite elements, for which the degrees of freedom are coincided with the mesh nodes.

```
fespace Vh(Th,P1);
Vh f;

real[int] pot(Vh.ndof);

for(int i=0;i<Vh.ndof;i++){
    pot[i]=something;   //assign values or read them from a file 
}

f[]=pot;
```